# On computation of pyramidal optical flow

Tags: python, image-processing, opticalflow

I have a question regarding the pyramid approach used in optical flow algorithms. Actually, the size of my memory does not allow me to store all the images in the pyramid, and I cannot average the images one by one at each level to obtain the desired sub-image. My question is, can we directly average the original image and obtain a sub-image at a specific level? If yes, how can we do it using a Gaussian filter?

The images are (grayscale) voxel-based and have a size of 2000x2000x2000. I am using a machine equipped with an Nvidia A100 GPU with 16GB of RAM. The code is written in Python.

Comment: you want to calculate optical flow on a device that doesn't even have enough RAM to hold a few copies of an image? details please.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In fact, I am trying to compute the optical flow for large 3D images. The memory size does not allow me to store all the images at once. Therefore, I need to resize the input images at each level of the pyramid, but this process takes time. My question is, is there a possibility to directly construct the sub-images directly from the original image?

Comment: yes, there's a way. details please.

Comment: I would like to know what other details you would like to have?

Comment: what makes those images "3D" (voxels? point clouds? depth maps? stereo pair?), the sizes of those images, the specs on the device that is to run this calculation, ... you know, _be forthcoming_. you are looking for help. be specific.

Comment: The images are (grayscale) voxel-based and have a size of 2000x2000x2000.  I am using a machine equipped with an Nvidia A100 GPU with 16GB of RAM. The code is written in Python.

Comment: Of course you can compute any layer of the pyramid directly. You just need to know the scale parameter for that level (the sigma of the Gaussian filter). What pyramid approach are you following? Is it an implementation in an existing library that you want to adapt? Or are you starting from scratch? What language are you using? What imaging library?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your comment.  My idea is to create a Python function using Numba (from scratch) that directly averages an image. How can we determine, for example, the sigma value of the Gaussian filter?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz To reassure you, this is purely an academic application and will be published as open source soon.

Comment: Typically, if you want to downsample an image by a factor of N, you’d apply a Gaussian with a sigma of N first. You then get very little aliasing (it does make the subsampled image look a bit blurry, so often 0.5N looks better, allowing for some more aliasing). But you need smoothing anyway to apply optical flow, so the blurriness is actually good.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you very much, I will try the proposed approach.